# How to prevent phpmailer sending embedded image as an attachment on Gmail?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am sending an email with the logo of a company in it. However, I find it annoying when it shows the .png file on the list of emails on Gmail. Upon clicking the email, the logo is there and there's no attachment (which is good). But I really need to remove the file when viewing on the email list. See the image below.

[image]

is there a way where I can remove this "email-logo.png"?

```
.
.
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('img/email-logo.png','logo');
.
.
$mail->Body = "<img  src='cid:logo'>";
.
.
```

Comment: You can't have it both ways. If you want the logo to show up when the mail is opened it has to be included as an attachment. As the answer below shows, removing the attachment will remove the logo from the mail too.

Comment: @Dave have any idea on how some companies do it? e.g PayPal, Facebook, Freelancer they have logos on them but do not show up as an attachment. Some even have photo images on them but do not show up as an attachment too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
$mail->clearAttachments();
```

Comment: It works on removing the png file on the email list, but when I open the email, the logo also doesn't show up. I want it to show up on my email content.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved to putting the src attribute of the image to a remote link e.g `src="http://somesite.com/image.png"`. I resolved to this since I always saw embedded images always coming as attachments as you have mentioned. But some clients block remote content as I have seen with this.